# 0x800700b7 Error in deploying website to IIS

Tags: iis, error-handling, webdeploy

There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

How to resolve this?

When i try to run the website i have this error: There is a duplicate system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler section defined

But i don't have a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler in the web.config. And when i delete this line then it complains about a duplicate of the next line, and so on until I remove almost all of the config sections.I have tried changing the appPoll to version 2 instead of version 4 But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve the problem by deleting  the configuration of web.config, in this case you may need to check whether there are multiple configuration files web.config. For example, one in the root directory and one in the virtual directory.

Just refer to this similar case: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5241f8f9-670d-43e6-a857-e7720350a5dd/config-errorthere-is-a-duplicate-error-systemwebextensionsscriptingscriptresourcehandler?forum=iis7general